# Количество одинаковых элементов в выборке для каждой группы

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Всем привет! Есть набор `div` элементов с атрибутами `data-service_id` и `data-service_model` (тип модели). У каждого типа модели есть `id` услуги. Этот `id` может повторяться. 
С кодом думаю будет нагляднее:

```
<div class="item" data-service_id="1" data-service_model="cover">Разный</div>
<div class="item" data-service_id="15" data-service_model="cover">Одинаковый</div>
<div class="item" data-service_id="15" data-service_model="cover">Одинаковый</div>


<div class="item" data-service_id="1" data-service_model="services">Разный</div>
<div class="item" data-service_id="10" data-service_model="services">Одинаковый</div>
<div class="item" data-service_id="10" data-service_model="services">Одинаковый</div>


<div class="item" data-service_id="5" data-service_model="service-Option">Разный</div>
<div class="item" data-service_id="8" data-service_model="service-Option">Одинаковый</div>
<div class="item" data-service_id="8" data-service_model="service-Option">Одинаковый</div>
```

Хотелось бы вывести все дубли и не дубли в массив типа

```
[{"service_model": "cover", "service_id": "15", "count": "2"}, {"service_model": "service", "service_id": "1", "count": "1"}, ... ]
```

То есть посчитать кол-во одинаковый по `id` и `service_model` , но и выводить кол-во даже если один элемент.

Я делала выборку всех элементов и по `.each` получала каждый элемент, но как считать кол-во вхождений не могу понять(((

Не хотелось бы выбирать конкретно по `id` , так как параметр меняется. Подскажите как лучше сделать? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Придется два раза проходить по данным для такой структуры, первый раз что бы посчитать, второй для нужного преобразования. Хотя может Вам подойдет и просто первый проход с результатом в `allItems`.

```js
//считаем количество id для каждого сервиса 
var allItems = {};
$('.item').each(function( index, el ) {
    var service_model = $(el).data("service_model"),
        service_id = $(el).data("service_id");
    if(allItems[service_model] == undefined){
        allItems[service_model] = {};
        allItems[service_model][service_id] = 1;
    } else if(allItems[service_model][service_id] == undefined) {
     allItems[service_model][service_id] = 1;
    } else {
        allItems[service_model][service_id] += 1;
    }
})

//преобразуем в нужную структуру
var mass = [];
for (service in allItems){
    for(id in allItems[service]){
        mass.push({"service_model": service, "service_id": id, "count": allItems[service][id]});
    }
}
console.log(mass)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item" data-service_id="1" data-service_model="cover">Разный</div>
<div class="item" data-service_id="15" data-service_model="cover">Одинаковый</div>
<div class="item" data-service_id="15" data-service_model="cover">Одинаковый</div>


<div class="item" data-service_id="1" data-service_model="services">Разный</div>
<div class="item" data-service_id="10" data-service_model="services">Одинаковый</div>
<div class="item" data-service_id="10" data-service_model="services">Одинаковый</div>


<div class="item" data-service_id="5" data-service_model="service-Option">Разный</div>
<div class="item" data-service_id="8" data-service_model="service-Option">Одинаковый</div>
<div class="item" data-service_id="8" data-service_model="service-Option">Одинаковый</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить вам следующий алгоритм:

1. Заводим ассоциативный массив (объект), где ключи - это id (можно модели), а значения - объекты из пар: модель и количество. (пример кода)
2. Идем по всем элементам, встречаем очередной - если его id уже есть в нашем массиве, то работает с соответствующим элементом, если нет - создаем. Внутри этого элемента (объект пар модель - количество) аналогично: если есть такая модель - увеличиваем кол-во на 1, если нет - создаем новую пару модель - количество 1.
3. Обходим все элементы и получаем количества всех вариантов (выборку можно делать по `$(".item")`)
4. Чтобы получить массив, который хотите, надо просто обойти в цикле в значения полученного ассоциативного массиива-объекта (2 вложенных цикла)

Вот пример нашего ассоциативного массива:

```
{
 "1": {
      "cover":1,
      "services":1
    },
 "15":{"cover":2},
// и так далее
}
```

Вот весь код, который это делает. Можно откопировать в .html файл и посмотреть в браузере. Однако по сути вам интересен только тег `<sctipt>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var elems = $(".item");
                var assoc = {}; // завели объект-массив
                elems.each(function (i, elem) { // перебор
                    if (!(elem.dataset.service_id in assoc)) { // если еще не встречали такого id
                        assoc[elem.dataset.service_id] = {}; // заведем новый элемент
                    }
                    if (!(elem.dataset.service_model in assoc[elem.dataset.service_id])) { // если не встречали такую модель с таким id
                        assoc[elem.dataset.service_id][elem.dataset.service_model] = 1; // заведем модель и количество у нее 1
                    }
                    else {
                        assoc[elem.dataset.service_id][elem.dataset.service_model]++; // если встречали, то просто увеличим количество
                    }
                    $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(assoc)); // выведем результат
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="item" data-service_id="1" data-service_model="cover">Разный</div>
        <div class="item" data-service_id="15" data-service_model="cover">Одинаковый</div>
        <div class="item" data-service_id="15" data-service_model="cover">Одинаковый</div>

        <div class="item" data-service_id="1" data-service_model="services">Разный</div>
        <div class="item" data-service_id="10" data-service_model="services">Одинаковый</div>
        <div class="item" data-service_id="10" data-service_model="services">Одинаковый</div>

        <div class="item" data-service_id="5" data-service_model="service-Option">Разный</div>
        <div class="item" data-service_id="8" data-service_model="service-Option">Одинаковый</div>
        <div class="item" data-service_id="8" data-service_model="service-Option">Одинаковый</div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: у меня данные динамические и нет заранее известного ассоциативного массива. Это если я правильно поняла ваш вариант )

Comment: @ennet так его надо на ходу делать `assoc['1']={'cover':1}`. у вас же всегда в div'е только 2 свойства, с которыми работаем `data-service_id` и `data-service_model` ?

Comment: да только эти 2

Comment: @ennet обновил ответ. JS - весьма динамичен, массив-объект можно набирать на ходу . Преобразование в нужную структуры, выполните сами, или посмотрите у Alex Krass